# Electric field of material

Tags: electromagnetism, electrons, electric-current, charge

Is it correct if I say that each material has some electric field? Atoms has protons and electrons and these charges creates el. fields. Or electric field needs to be created?

Comment: Depends on what is your "some".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every compound or atom will have same number of protons that of electrons. So the electric field of protons will be nullified by that of neutrons. Hence the electric field will be almost zero(it will be very very very less due to the distance between protons and neutrons) . Hence when you transfer electrons from one to other substance the number will not remain same which will now produce a distinguishable electric field.